# Flat observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Everywhere I see that Knockout observableArray contains dictionary like:

```
var people = ko.observableArray([
    {
        name: 'john',
        age: 27
    }
]);
```

But can we have just a flat array like `ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3]);`? And if yes then how can we iterate over it in template?

Comment: Yes. In your first example the array contains a list of objects. `[1, 2, 3]` is an array of numbers. Same thing, different data types.

Comment: Okay. But how to iterate over those values in template? In examples that I found there is always an object inside array and there is a reference to properties of this object? How to refer to flat array values in template by `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$data` to iterate through a flat array in a template:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        The current item is: <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Refer to the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html), section *Note 1: Referring to each array entry using $data*.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.